# AWS "This resource policy contains an unsupported principal" using .Net NotPrincipal with DENY

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I am trying to add a simple policy statement

```
var secretValueGetterRole = Role.FromRoleName(
            this,
            "secretValueGetterRole ",
            $"roleName");
```

above I am getting the role I wish to give access to

```
var secretToApplyPolicyTo = new Amazon.CDK.AWS.SecretsManager.Secret(
            this,
            "secret",
            new SecretProps(),)
```

I create a secret, I am omitting the secret props in this example to avoid too much information.

```
secretToApplyPolicyTo.AddToResourcePolicy(
            new PolicyStatement(
                new PolicyStatementProps
                {
                    Effect = Effect.DENY,
                    NotPrincipals = new[]
                    {
                        new ArnPrincipal(secretValueGetterRole.RoleArn),
                    },
                    Actions = new[]
                    {
                        "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                    },
                }));
```

here I am adding a policy statement to the secret.  this will deny all principals but the selected role from getting the value of the secret.

Problem:  this synthesizes without issue, but when it tries to deploy to AWS it is giving this error:

```
CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::SecretsManager::ResourcePolicy         | secretToApplyPolicyTo/Policy (secretToApplyPolicyToPolicy7721B0CC) This resource policy contains an unsupported principal. (Service: AWSSecretsManager; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocumentException; Request ID: ########-####-####-####-############; Proxy: null)
```

I have not seen any examples of doing this for .Net.  I have seen other answers where they recommend using 'assumed-role\roleName' instead of 'role\roleName' and using JSON,  however the NotPrincipal' property requires an object of type Principal, so it seems different to do it in .Net CDK.

I am not sure how to do this in .Net CDK, and that is the framework I need to do it in.